# Find the dual problem and determine if it's convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

> min $3x_1^2+x_1x_2+2x_2^2$
> s.t $3x_1^2+x_1x_2+2x_2^2+x_1-x_2\geq1$
> $ x_1\geq 2x_2$
> Find the dual problem and determine if it's convex.

I've set the lagrangian to be $L(x,\lambda,\eta)=3x_1^2+x_1x_2+2x_2^2-\lambda(3x_1^2+x_1x_2+2x_2^2+x_1-x_2-1)+\eta(2x_2-x_1)=3x_1^2(1-\lambda)+x_1x_2(1-\lambda)+2x_2^2(1-\lambda)+\lambda(-x_1+x_2+1)+\eta(2x_2-x_1)$
I know that I will get a finite solution if the matrix of the quad part is PSD which is the same as $0\leq \lambda\leq1$ but I got stuck on finding the dual problem from here. I've tried to minimize w.r.t to $x_1,x_2$ same time here.
Edit I've tried without $\eta(2x_2-x_1)$ and got that the dual problem is $q(\lambda)=\frac{-29\lambda^2+23\lambda}{23(1-\lambda)}$ but not sure if it's the right some help would be nice

Comment: The problem is convex as the objective function is convex (it has a PSD matrix representation as you pointed out) and the constraints define a convex set (again, easy to check, just some pen and paper work). As for the dual problem, after defining the Lagrangian you need to differentiate w.r.t $x_1, x_2$ and find the optimal $x_1, x_2$ solution, with $\lambda, \eta$ remaining in the solution. Then you plug these optimal solutions back to the Lagrangian and you get a dual problem, where now you have $\lambda, \eta$ as variables instead of $x_1, x_2$, and recall that the domain is non-negative

Comment: It's not a difficult question but definitely a lot of "manual labour" - proving convexity of the domain, differentiation and finding optimal $x_1, x_2$... reminds me 1st year calculus courses

Comment: right thanks :),when you mean the problem is convex? you mean the dual or primal? because the primal isn't convex because the first constraint is not convex

Comment: and I thought there is something easier than just alot of calculations

Comment: A *convex problem* means minimizing a convex function over a convex domain. Equivalently, maximizing a *concave* function over convex domain is also considered a convex problem. Notice that the dual problem of any primal, convex or not, is always a convex problem (the proof of that is not short... you can look it up). In your case the problem is not convex due to the first constraint.

Comment: Lastly, there is the question of *strong duality*, which means that the optimal values of the primal and dual are equal. There are some conditions for strong duality to apply, mainly having a convex primal problem but also some regularity conditions. When a primal-dual pair doesn't have strong duality, then the dual problem is only a lower bound on the primal value, which is known as *weak duality*.